# Unable to Hot Reload Visual Studio 2022 .NET 4.7.2 Web api project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload, .net-4.7.2

Ive got visual studio v17.8.1. Tried to hot reload my .NET 4.7.2 web api project. When I change anything in code I get info that its not possible to attach to IIS process and hot reload. If I dont debug with attaching to process my hotreload is grayed out.

How I can make my .net 4.7.2 web api project to be hot reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Setting COMPLUS_ForceEnC = 1 fixes the issue:

Run cmd as Administrator

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set apppool "DefaultAppPool" /+environmentVariables.add[@start,name='COMPLUS_ForceEnC',value='1']
```

It will set environmentVariable`COMPLUS_ForceEnC` to 1 in applicationHost.config.